# Cocoa: NSStepperCell in NSTableView

Tags: cocoa, macos

I can't seem to get a normal NSStepperCell to be the type of a cell in a NSTableView. When I'm using IB, it wouldn't let me set the column cell type to NSStepperCell.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Allright, I solved it, sorry guys.

What you have to do is to programmatically do the following:

 NSStepperCell * steppercell = [[[NSStepperCell alloc] init] autorelease]; 
 [[self.tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"stepper"] setDataCell:steppercell];

It's impossible to set the cell type in IB to NSStepperCell.

Comment: Add this as an answer and mark it accepted so you're cleaning up after yourself.  This prevents others wasting their time looking into unanswered questions. :-)

Comment: Why? Others might be searching for an answer to this very question using the same language / phrasing as George. This site's very purpose is so others can learn from existing questions as much as by asking their own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, I solved it, sorry guys.
What you have to do is to programmatically do the following:

NSStepperCell * steppercell = [[[NSStepperCell alloc] init] autorelease];    [[self.tableView tableColumnWithIdentifier:@"stepper"] setDataCell:steppercell];

It's impossible to set the cell type in IB to NSStepperCell.